# Toronto - Quito via Cleveland and Houston, do I check in for every flight?

Tags: air-travel, usa, transit, airports, houston

I am a bit confused... I am an Ecuadorian citizen and I hold a US tourist Visa and a Canadian temporary residency visa...

I bought a ticket from Toronto to Quito on United's website...

My intinerary starts on Toronto goes to Cleveland, after three hours goes to Houston and after 3 hours goes to Ecuador.

Even though I bought the ticket on united the first flight from Toronto to Cleveland is operated by Air Canada Jazz...

My question is: do I have to go through customs in Cleveland or is it enough to do it in Toronto? (I understand you do it at Pearson)...

And also, I how do I check in for my flights? I only got one confirmation number and this takes me to the Air Canada website but is this enough? Do I check in for every flight on that website?

Finally, what about my luggage? Do I need to worry about checking it in, out on every American connection? Or there is no need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have one number for your entire reservation, your baggage will be checked in once.

You will also get boarding passes for all your flights when you initially check-in at Pearson.

The only glitch in the process is that US has their own immigration/customs policy which applies to all passengers, even those in transit. You have to go through immigration and passport control. Thankfully, you can do this process directly at Pearson ([here are the details](http://www.torontopearson.com/Departing_to_usa.aspx#)); effectively making you a domestic passenger once you land in the US.

Now all that's left is the waiting :)